# Is it more efficient to make an functor with no members a class member object or a stack object?

Tags: c++, performance

I have a functor with no member variables. I am wondering if it is more efficient to create this functor on the fly as needed or cache it as a member variable. There are issues with regards to empty-base class optimization and cache locality that I'm not sure about.

```
struct Foo
{
int operator()(const MyData& data) const { ... }
};
```

Comment: Try both in a loop of a million calls, and time each loop. Both without and with optimization enabled.

Comment: ... and/or compile the stuff and look at the assembly. I believe there is no reason the operator cannot be inlined.

Comment: On the fly as needed. The constructor is a no-op, the object is never referenced, so all overhead will be flushed by the optimizer pipeline.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For an empty object, just create it in the stack. Adding the functor to your type as a member will make all of your objects larger. Adding it as a base (to make use of the empty base optimization), will yield a weird design in which your type implements `operator()(const MyData&)` for no reason. Even if you make it private the operator will be there.

Since the type has no members, there is no *cache locality* issues, as no data to be accessed. The main use of a stateless functor is to allow the compiler to inline the call to the function (compared with a free function with the same name)

Answer (score 0):

The general rule for optimization is:  code to make it work first, optimize only when it is proven to be necessary (in other words, you've profiled your code and found a bottleneck that needs to be addressed to greatly improve performance).